# how to group a column and that the other column is grouped to generate a contingency table in R

Tags: r, database, datatable, chi-squared, contingency

I need to group the column "Estrato" 1 and 2 into low, 3,4,5 into medium, 6 into high and others, taking into account column "Callevive" the format of colum "Estrato" is factor. to generate a contingency table like in the image.

```
 enter code here > head(datos17,25)
       Estrato                Callevive
    1        2 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    2        4 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    3        3 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    4        0 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    5        3 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    6        3 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    7        3 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    8        3 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    9        3 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    10       2 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    11       3 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    12       2 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    13       2 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    14       3 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    15       2 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    16       2           Muy Satisfecho
    17       2       Un Poco Satisfecho
    18       3 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    19       2 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    20       2 Moderadamente Satisfecho
    21       2           Muy Satisfecho
    22       2           Muy Satisfecho
    23       2           Muy Satisfecho
    24       2           Muy Satisfecho
    25       5 Moderadamente Satisfecho
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    mutate(group = cut(
        Estrato,
        breaks = c(-1, 2, 5, Inf),
        labels = c("low", "medium", "high"))) %>%
    group_by(group, Callevive) %>%
    tally() %>%
    spread(Callevive, n)
## A tibble: 2 x 4
## Groups:   group [2]
#  group  `Moderadamente Satisfecho` `Muy Satisfecho` `Un Poco Satisfecho`
#  <fct>                       <int>            <int>                <int>
#1 low                             8                5                    1
#2 medium                         11               NA                   NA
```

Explanation: We bin entries in `Estrato` into `low` (`0,1,2`), `medium` (`3,4,5`), and `high` (`>6`) groups, then use `tally` and `spread` to output a contingency table.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "      Estrato                Callevive
    1        2 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    2        4 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    3        3 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    4        0 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    5        3 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    6        3 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    7        3 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    8        3 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    9        3 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    10       2 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    11       3 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    12       2 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    13       2 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    14       3 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    15       2 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    16       2           'Muy Satisfecho'
    17       2       'Un Poco Satisfecho'
    18       3 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    19       2 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    20       2 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'
    21       2           'Muy Satisfecho'
    22       2           'Muy Satisfecho'
    23       2           'Muy Satisfecho'
    24       2           'Muy Satisfecho'
    25       5 'Moderadamente Satisfecho'", row.names = 1)
```

Comment: thank you for responding, the code generates entries with inf in the table, I think it is "breacks", because it takes them as a numeric. can you explain in more detail how it works breacks.what happens if the column Estrato were factor?

Comment: @Jonas I would convert `Estrato` to a `numeric` vector with `as.numeric(as.character(...))`. Then bin entries using `cut` as before.